# Ovverturned how can they do it

Tags: landlord, tenancy-rules

Had eviction papers filed on me, motioned to have a stay of writ and payment plan which was granted.  The first payment date isn't even here yet and landlady ex parte got the stay overturned.  What can I do now?  I didn't even know she went back to court.  Why do they even have stays if they can be overturned before the stipulations haven't been met yet?  Frantic.  This is in Washington.

Comment: See https://www.washingtonlawhelp.org/issues/housing/eviction

Answer (score 2):

You can and should hire an attorney. The thing with evictions is that there are lots of motions that can be filed, under [RCW 59.18.410](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=59.18.410). The landlord may have filed a motion to execute a writ of restitution. You would have been served with notice of a hearing; but that does not mean that you actually got the notice (see [the notice sections of the law](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=59.18&full=true#59.18.055)). It is enough if the landlord tries three times over two days at different times. Since you did not know about the hearing therefore did not show up, default judgment was probably entered against you. This is a thing that your attorney can straighten out, however, there is no guarantee that this will solve your problem. But, the landlord will at least have to say in court how he served you.